# Merge conflict on sass compiled css file

Tags: css, git, merge, sass

We're using a git repo (just a private repo on Git, so no remote server) that is using a webhook to continuously deploy to an Azure site.

Our project is using SASS, and every time we execute `git pull` we have a merge conflict on `style.css`.

Now, ideally I'd love to not have the css files included in the git repo, but given the lack of a build step for me to execute a "hey, foo, compile, combine, minify!" task, I'm not sure how to get around the merge conflict.

[This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337498/azure-websites-and-sass) would get pretty close, but we're developing exclusively in OSX, which is the one caveat preventing us from going that route.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you create a build step?

Comment: If you look at the SO post, it's because the build step occurs on an Azure server, which has limitations we can't work around. Where else would I create a build step? Anything I would do within Git / locally would have to get checked in to deploy out to Azure, no?

Comment: Would https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass be an option?

Comment: I'm already using grunt to compile our SCSS to CSS. The merge conflict is the result of my colleague changing one of the SCSS files, which modifies the generated CSS file. This is where the practice of not checking in CSS files makes sense. Instead, you add a build step on a server which runs the compilation / combination / minification for you. We don't have the luxury of doing that, hence this post

Comment: you could try this: http://blog.andrewray.me/dealing-with-compiled-files-in-git/